# error during deploying custom theme in magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

i am working on theme in magento 2,but i am getting error in terminal(CMD),the error message is  **"unable to load theme by specified key:My/Helloworld"** when i run php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy, my required file are 
**app\design\frontend\My\Helloworld\composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magento/theme-frontend-My",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**app\design\frontend\My\Helloworld\registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/My/Helloworld',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Try going through the steps [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html). Let us know if it helped.

Comment: clear the cache and run the bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy again. This way works fine for me

Comment: @AnandOntigeri, Yes it's working fine.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar for me it is not working....

Comment: you can also follow link @https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/theming-in-magento-2-part-1 .

Answer (score 5):

A common oversight which could throw this error is forgetting to run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This allows Magento to register your theme in the 'theme' table of the Magento database. You can check if your theme is registered via the mysql command line:

```
mysql> use <your magento database>;
mysql> SELECT * FROM theme;
```

If your theme is registered also make sure that the 'type' column value for your theme record is 0. Values of 1 can also lead to this error.

Answer (score 1):

have you declare theme name from `di.xml` like below. Below code is the example for creating backend.

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="frontend" xsi:type="string">Magento/luma</item>
            <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Learning/backend</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

and run the below commands in `CLI`

1. php bin/magento cache:clean
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

if still not working go to admin panel clear the cache and clear the flush and re run above commands it will work.

Comment: Let me get this clear: do I need to add this to the di.xml of my module? Still doesn't work for me ...

Comment: @GielBerkers, Yes ad the `di.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, this may be due to cache files

Remove following directories `pub/static, var/cache, var/composer_home, var/generation, var/page_cache,var/view_preprocessed`

Then run the following command line from terminal/shell:
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: After following your instructions I got: `There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace`