# Magento 2 : Can't deploy my custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, deployment

I've created a theme in Magento 2, but when I'm trying to deploy my Magento site to a server, it's static files don't get generated. I've already tried the solution in [error during deploying custom theme in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96017/error-during-deploying-custom-theme-in-magento-2), but that doesn't work for me.

What happens is when I run `bin/magento setup:static-content-deploy`, Magento goes and create the static content for `Magento/blank` and `Magento/luma` (and the adminhtml template), but not for my custom template.

registration.php:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Happy/Foundation',
    __DIR__
);
```

Locally, in developer mode, everything works fine. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I already found the answer: it turns out Magento only renders themes when there is content in the `web` folder inside your template.